# visual studio 2012 compile times

Tags: c++, time, compilation, visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does C++ compilation take so long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318398/why-does-c-compilation-take-so-long)
>   [Visual studio 2012 slow compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057396/visual-studio-2012-slow-compile-time)

I'm using visual studio 2012 and the time it takes to compile is way to long. About 20 seconds just for a measly 50 lines of code. I thought it was my computers fault but c# compiles fine on it just not c++. I know that c++ takes longer to compile but 20 seconds is ridiculous.

Here's the code I'm trying to compile which takes about 20 seconds to compile.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Entity
{
protected: 
    int health; 
public: 
    void SetHealth(int value)
    {
        health = value;
    }

    void DisplayHealth()
    {
        cout << "Entity: " << health << endl;
    }
};

class Player : public Entity
{
private:
    int xp;
public: 
    void DisplayHealth()
    {
        cout << "Player: " << health << endl;
    }
};

class Enemy : public Entity
{

};

int main()
{
    Player player; 

    Entity *entity = &player;

    entity->SetHealth(10); 
    player.DisplayHealth();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My code shouldn't be taking 20 seconds to compile. Using visual studio 2010 the compile times weren't that slow and same with code::blocks. Isn't visual studio 2012 supposed to be an improvement?

Comment: Are you using precompiled headers? Looks like you aren't from the code above. Try using them and see if your compilation times improve.

Comment: Precompiled headers aren't going to make a big difference in a one file project.  I compiled your code in Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 and it took ~1 second for both compilers in either debug or release mode.  I don't have 2012 to test with.

Comment: why do you ask [exactly the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057396/visual-studio-2012-slow-compile-time) again? You shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

I've compiled this piece of code under my installation of VS2012 and it took about 3 seconds to build a project with this only file. Probably, you have troubles in your VS2012 installation. Try running it in [safe mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to disable extensions.